# input type text cant be typed into in ie 11 if created using javascript! :(

Tags: javascript, text, input, internet-explorer-11, edit

This is the simplest example i created and this does not work in ie 11 :(
It literally will not let me type into the text input!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var text = document.createElement('input');
text.type = 'text';
document.documentElement.appendChild(text);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get around this ridiculous bug?
I am building a sophisticated website that generates most of the html using javascript.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at how to ask a question using a [minimal, complete, verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been there... I had to force the focus on the input.

```
$("input").click(function(){ $(this).closest('input').focus()})
```

Comment: hard to believe isn't it! I spent my morning trying to work around another bug with tables in firefox. But this! It's ridiculous that something so simple isnt working right, anyway thanks man just trying it!

Comment: ok this does work actually when done on a click event. The problem was that the click event was not firing i had to use addEventListener in ie.

Comment: Happy that worked, please mark as correct answer. :). @sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd

Comment: how do i do that :/?

Answer (score 1):

`document.documentElement` will be your html page and you are trying to append an element as a sibling of the `documentElement`'s innerHTML.

instead of `documentElement` use `body`:

```js
var text = document.createElement('input');
text.type = 'text';
document.body.appendChild(text);
```

Comment: cant really do this though. The problem is occurring many levels up from the documentElement. I use the documentElement for other reasons.

Comment: @sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfd you need to put all the elements inside body tag. `document.documentElement` is the document itself. that would make it invalid.

Comment: ok so i tried it. It works at the level of document.body but does not work on my input type text nested in parent divs. This is the actual site if you want to see what i mean: 86.171.165.12